# Dhall environment variable value as a union alternative

Tags: dhall

I'm just starting out with Dhall and I've been stumped by this problem. I'm trying to generate YAML files where an argument is set by an environment variable, in this case `DHALL_TARGET`. Basically I'm trying to do this:

```
let Env = < demo | live >
in  [ ./project.dhall Env.env:DHALL_TARGET ]
```

The above obviously doesn't work because `Env.env:DHALL_TARGET` is invalid syntax. What is the correct way to interpret an environment variable as a union alternative?

I'm running it like this right now:

```
DHALL_TARGET=live dhall-to-yaml-ng --explain --documents --file ./project.dhall
```

Comment: This is a frequently requested feature, but it hasn't been standardized or implemented yet: https://github.com/dhall-lang/dhall-lang/issues/994